# How to dynamically create and change stream targets in wowza streaming engine

Tags: java, api, module, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I'm developing a server side module and I want to dynamically change the stream targets based on the incoming streams. I want to know how to do it using java API's in wowza streaming engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the com.wowza.wms.pushpublish.* packages (documented in the serverapi that comes with the Wowza installation and on the wowza site) to intercept the publish event and create the stream target (previously called push publish). Here is an example code that creates an RTMP Stream Target prefixed with "push-" to the same Wowza application.

```js
package com.wowza.wms.plugin.pushpublish.module;

import java.util.*;

import com.wowza.wms.amf.AMFPacket;
import com.wowza.wms.application.IApplicationInstance;
import com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLoggerFactory;
import com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleBase;
import com.wowza.wms.pushpublish.protocol.rtmp.*;
import com.wowza.wms.stream.*;

public class ModulePushPublishSimpleExample extends ModuleBase
{
 Map<IMediaStream, PushPublishRTMP> publishers = new HashMap<IMediaStream, PushPublishRTMP>();
 
 class StreamNotify implements IMediaStreamActionNotify2
 {

  public void onPlay(IMediaStream stream, String streamName, double playStart, double playLen, int playReset)
  {
  }

  public void onPause(IMediaStream stream, boolean isPause, double location)
  {
  }

  public void onSeek(IMediaStream stream, double location)
  {
  }

  public void onStop(IMediaStream stream)
  {
  }

  public void onMetaData(IMediaStream stream, AMFPacket metaDataPacket)
  {
  }

  public void onPauseRaw(IMediaStream stream, boolean isPause, double location)
  {
  }
  
  public void onPublish(IMediaStream stream, String streamName, boolean isRecord, boolean isAppend)
  {
   if (!streamName.startsWith("push-")) // this is here to avoid looping pushes
   {
    try
    {
     IApplicationInstance appInstance = stream.getStreams().getAppInstance();
     
     synchronized(publishers)
     {
      PushPublishRTMP publisher = new PushPublishRTMP();
      
      // Source stream
      publisher.setAppInstance(appInstance);
      publisher.setSrcStreamName(streamName);

      // Destination stream
      String dstHost = "localhost";
      int dstPort = 1935;
      String dstApplication = appInstance.getApplication().getName();
      String dstStreamName = "push-"+streamName;
      String flashVersion = PushPublishRTMP.CURRENTFMLEVERSION;
      
      // Uncomment and update with Akamai account info if pushing to Akamai
      //String streamId = "32637";
      //String akamaiUsername = "134706";
      //String akamaiPassword = "wowza";
      //boolean isPrimary = true;
      //dstHost = (isPrimary?"p":"b")+".ep"+streamId+".i.akamaientrypoint.net";
      //dstApplication = "EntryPoint";
      //dstStreamName = streamName+"_1_950"+"@"+streamId;
      //flashVersion = PushPublishRTMP.CURRENTFLASHVERSION;
      //
      //publisher.setAkamaiUserName(akamaiUsername);
      //publisher.setAkamaiPassword(akamaiPassword);

      // Destination stream
      publisher.setHost(dstHost);
      publisher.setPort(dstPort);
      publisher.setDstApplicationName(dstApplication);
      publisher.setDstStreamName(dstStreamName);
      publisher.setConnectionFlashVersion(flashVersion);
      
      // Uncomment if pushing to Adobe Media Server
      //publisher.setSendOriginalTimecodes(true);
      //publisher.setOriginalTimecodeThreshold(0x100000);

      // SecureToken shared secret
      //publisher.setSecureTokenSharedSecret("#ed%h0#w@1");
   
      publisher.setSendFCPublish(true);
      publisher.setSendReleaseStream(true);
      publisher.setSendOnMetadata(true);
      publisher.setDebugLog(true);
      publisher.setDebugPackets(false);
         
      // Uncomment if target server protected using RTMP authentication
      //PushPublishRTMPAuthProviderAdobe adobeRTMPAuthProvider = new PushPublishRTMPAuthProviderAdobe();
      //adobeRTMPAuthProvider.init(publisher);
      //adobeRTMPAuthProvider.setUserName("username");
      //adobeRTMPAuthProvider.setPassword("password");
      //publisher.setRTMPAuthProvider(adobeRTMPAuthProvider);
      
      publisher.connect();
      publishers.put(stream, publisher);
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(null).error("ModulePushPublishSimpleExample#StreamNotify.onPublish: "+e.toString());
    }
   }
  }

  public void onUnPublish(IMediaStream stream, String streamName, boolean isRecord, boolean isAppend)
  {
   stopPublisher(stream);
  }
 }
 
 public void stopPublisher(IMediaStream stream)
 {
  try
  {
   synchronized(publishers)
   {
    PushPublishRTMP publisher = publishers.remove(stream);
    if (publisher != null)
     publisher.disconnect();
   }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(null).error("ModulePushPublishSimpleExample#StreamNotify.onPublish: "+e.toString());
  }
 }
 
 public void onStreamCreate(IMediaStream stream)
 {
  stream.addClientListener(new StreamNotify());
 }
 
 public void onStreamDestory(IMediaStream stream)
 {
  stopPublisher(stream);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michelle. I'll try this out and see the outcome.